# Datatable displaying 2 different entity tables with relation

Tags: jsf

my datatable

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:dataTable columnClasses="input-radio,input-label" id="account-table" value="#{accountController.items}" var="item" border="0">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
            </h:column> 
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

i have an account entity that is in relation with a user entity. Is there anyway to retrieve user datas from account rather than making 2 datatables for account and user?

getItems method

```
public DataModel getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    return items;

}
```

using JSF 2 and the manage beans are autogenerated using CRUD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `DataModel` class has access to the `user` entity, you can just traverse the relationship in your JSF page by chaining the objects:

- `#{item.name}` - access to the item name
- `#{item.user.name}` - access to the users name, if the user has a getter in item

E.g. your `DataModel`:

```
public class DataModel {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

The JSF page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:dataTable columnClasses="input-radio,input-label" id="account-table" value="#{accountController.items}" var="item" border="0">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.user.name}"/> <!-- traverse to user entity here -->
            </h:column> 
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```